# Can you say "Shehachiyanu" on a mortgage "burning"?

Tags: halacha, real-estate, shehecheyanu, borrowing

In the U.S., there is a custom to burn the mortgage paper after the last mortgage payment has been made. Should one say *Shehechiyanu* on the event of now officially owning his home?

Comment: Why not extend your question to paying off anything of value, e.g., a car, a diamond ring.  Consider that when you buy a new suit and put it on your credit card you still make the shehecheyanu when you put on the suit for the first time even though you have not yet paid the credit card.  Also consider that creditors consider you a home owner even before the mortgage is paid off.  So, add all this up and I would think that the answer to your interesting question is "no."

Comment: @MichaelKatz Fair argument to make. Might be an answer ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKatz Well people definitely make a shehechiyanu upon purchasing a house, even if they are committing themselves to 30 years of mortgage payments. But maybe you can say it again once all of the payments are complete. It's certainly a moment of significance.